# EF 6 'Bulk' insert with FK relationed models

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, clone, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk insert using EF (model first) on two tables that have a FK relationship (one to many). The code below properly inserts all of the Challenge entries but only inserts the X amount Shortages one time. My expectation... I have 10 shortages with 2 challenges. I should receive 2 challenge entries and 20 shortage entries. I am only seeing 10 challenge entries for the first shortage inserted. (the code below is simplified)

```
//class for cloning Shortage collection
public class ShortageCollection : Collection<Shortage>
    {
        public ShortageCollection(IList<Shortage> source) : base(source) { }

        public ShortageCollection() { }

        public ShortageCollection Clone()
        {
            return Clone(this);
        }
        public static ShortageCollection Clone(ShortageCollection shortage)
        {
            var res = new ShortageCollection();
            foreach (var s in shortage)
            {
                res.Add(s.Clone());
            }
        }
    }

 public class Shortage : StandardDB.Shortage
    {
       public Shortage Clone()
        {
            return new Shortage()
            {
                PART_NUMBER = this.PART_NUMBER,
                Note = this.Note,
                Qty = this.Qty,
                ResponseMachine = this.ResponseMachine
            };
        }
    }

public void CreateChallenge()
    {
        var JSONJobs = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<string[]>(Jobs);
        var JSONParts = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ChallengePartsList[]>(Parts);
        using (ARTEntities art = new ARTEntities())
        {
            art.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            art.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

            ShortageCollection sColl = new ShortageCollection();
            foreach(var part in JSONParts)
            {
                Shortage s = new Shortage()
                {
                    PART_NUMBER = part.Invid,
                    Note = Challenge,
                    Qty = part.Qty,
                    ResponseMachine = ResponseMachine
                };
                sColl.Add(s);
            }

            foreach (var job in JSONJobs) {
                Challenge c = new Challenge()
                {
                    InitiatorORG = Org,
                    TypeID = TypeID,
                    DISCRETE_JOB = job,
                    InitiatorPERSON_ID = InitiatorPersonID,
                    InitiatedDate = datenow,
                    Challenge1 = Challenge,
                    ChampionGroupID = ChampionGroupID,
                    StatusID = StatusID,
                    InitiatorGroupID = InitiatorGroupID,
                    DivisionID = DivisionID,
                    Shortages = sColl.Clone()
                };
                art.Challenges.Add(c);
            }
            art.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you are only creating 10 Shortages in memory. Your `Clone` method is a shallow clone, and doesn't go through and clone every object. Therefore you have 2 lists with 10 identical items (each pair of items point to exactly same memory reference).

What you need to do is DeepClone which is something like the following:

```
    public static ShortageCollection Clone(ShortageCollection shortage)
    {
        var res = new ShortageCollection();
        foreach(var s in shortage) {
            res.Add( s.Clone() );
        }

        return res;
    }
```

And in your shortage class:

```
public class Shortage
{
    public Shortage Clone()
    {
        return new Shortage()
        {
            SomeProp = this.SomeProp,
            SomeOtherProp = this.SomeOtherProp
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that if inside shortage any of those objects point to another entity, each pair will point to the same entity.

Search for DeepClone for more info

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Your code above produces this error. (local variable) Shortage s. 's' is a variable but used like a type.

Comment: Thanks. It appears as though it would work if I wasn't overriding a model first class. I get a  "The mapping 
of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'Shortage'. 
Previously found CLR type 'StandardDB.Shortage', newly found CLR type 'WebApps.Controllers.ChallengeController+Shortage'" error

Comment: Also, I had to use res.Add(s.Clone()), instead of r = s.Clone(), since it was a collection of shortages.

Comment: Interesting, what is your other type? Could you pose the 2 types includign namespaces? So i can test it out locally